# Django Models - 'Pcaps.uuid' must set unique=True because it is referenced by a foreign key

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, django-models

In essence I am trying to create a few tables that are populated with attributes of pcaps. I am receiving quite an odd error. This is the code in the models class:

```
class Pcaps(models.Model):
     uuid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     filename = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
     datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
     filehash = models.ForeignKey(Malwares, to_field="filehash", 
 db_column="filehash")

class PcapsIps(models.Model):
    domainname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    uuid = models.ForeignKey(Pcaps, to_field="uuid", db_column="uuid")

class PcapsPorts(models.Model):
   number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   uuid = models.ForeignKey(Pcaps, to_field="uuid", db_column="uuid")
```

The error in question is as follows:

ERRORS:

```
analyser.PcapsIps.uuid: (fields.E311) 'Pcaps.uuid' must set unique=True 
because it is referenced by a foreign key.
analyser.PcapsPorts.uuid: (fields.E311) 'Pcaps.uuid' must set unique=True because it is referenced by a foreign key.
```

Comment: Why is it odd? The error is very clear, foreign key must be unique.

Answer (score 7):

You have to understand how a foreign key works under the hood, i.e. in whatever database system you're using. A foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table (corresponding to a Django model) that uniquely identifies a row of another (or the same) table. Normally, this is done by primary key, because that is guaranteed to be unique. If you have a reason to do so, you can set `to_field` to reference a different row in the other table/model, but then that field also has to be unique. Thus you need:

```
uuid = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
```

EDIT: Oh, by the way, if you're using Django 1.8 or later, it now has a `UUIDField`. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)